# Remove uploaded files from the global request instance in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

In my Laravel API Model *created* event listener, I automatically check if the request has a file named *image* or *id_image*, then save it to storage and persist in DB, of which the table has support for two types of files, [*image*, *id_image*].

Now the problem is that my Vue-powered front end is designed to only pass *image* as an uploaded file, so I have to use the other request parameters to determine if the update requires me to save *image* or  *id_image*.

So I wrote a simple middleware to handle the scenarios:

```php
class ModifyRequest
{
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next, $action, ...$params)
    {
        if (method_exists($this, $action)) {
            $request = $this->$action($request, ...$params);
        }

        return $next($request);
    }

    public function replace(Request $request, $key, $with_key): Request
    {
        return Request::create(
            $request->url(),
            $request->method(),
            $request->except($key),
            $request->cookies->all(),[],
            collect([$with_key => $key])->map(function ($key, $with_key) use ($request) {
                return $request->hasFile($key) ? $request->file($key) : null;
            })->filter()->toArray(),
            $request->server(),
            $request->getContent()
        );
    }
}
```

And in my route:

```php
Route::prefix('vendors')->name('vendors.')
   ->middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'modify_request:replace,image,id_image'])
   ->group(function () {
       Route::apiResource('/verify', VerificationController::class)->only(['store', 'update']);
});
```

This works perfectly to add the *id_image* when required, the problem is, even though, *image* no longer exists in the middlware, it somehow still exists in every other part of the Api.
If I am unable to remove *image* from the request it means the the *image* from the request which is intended to be saved as *id_image* will save as *id_image* and also overwrite *image*.

SO how do I ensure that *image* is completely remove from the global request instance.